# Xcode chooses wrong ios team provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, profile, provisioning

I have two different "Teams" at my company and the both properly show up in the drop-down list within Xcode 5.1.1 on the "General" tab.  My understanding is once I choose the team, when I set the Code Signing Provisioning Profile to "iOS Team Provisioning Profile:*" then Xcode should be using the wildcard provisioning profile FOR THAT TEAM and not my other team.

But this is not the case.  It's choosing the wrong one and it's impossible to debug on my devices because those devices are all registered to the other team (on purpose, and need to stay that way).

Why does Xcode do this incorrectly and is there any way I can correct the problem?

Thanks,
Anthony